# ImageResizer.Net AzureReader2 Plugin not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, imageresizer

I am using the ImageResizer.NET library to read images from the Azure Blob Storage and resize them.

For that I needed to install AzureReader2 plugin and configure it in the web.config file.

I have the following line in the Web.Config.

```
<plugins>
  <add name="MvcRoutingShim" />
  <add name="PrettyGifs" />
  <add name="SimpleFilters" />
  <add name="AzureReader2" connectionString="StorageConnectionString" endpoint="http://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/" />
</plugins>
```

When I run my Web Role, I get the following error : **Settings must be of the form "name=value".**

What am I missing??

Comment: @user2981411 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51252296/documentation-on-how-to-use-imageflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### In AzureReader2, you must specify the actual connection string, not the name of the connection string

```
<plugins>
  <add name="MvcRoutingShim" />
  <add name="PrettyGifs" />
  <add name="SimpleFilters" />
  <add name="AzureReader2" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=myAccountName;AccountKey=myAccountKey" endpoint="http://<account>.blob.core.windows.net/" />
</plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

try with adding `prefix="~/img/"` in last tag.

**Make it as follows:**

```
<plugins>
  <add name="MvcRoutingShim" />
  <add name="PrettyGifs" />
  <add name="SimpleFilters" />
  <add name="AzureReader2" prefix="~/img/" connectionString="StorageConnectionString" endpoint="http://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/" />
</plugins>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Nope... It doesn't work... Still same error... 
      <add name="AzureReader2" prefix="~/img/"  vpp="false" connectionString="StorageConnectionString" endpoint="http://justlikeustorage.blob.core.windows.net/" />

Comment: I think it might have something to do with not finding CloudStorage Connection string... In the previous version, they had the following code in the App_Start event of Global.asx. Not sure what's the equivalent for StorageClient 2.0 CloudStorageAccount.SetConfigurationSettingPublisher((configName, configSettingPublisher) => {
    var connectionString = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(configName);
    configSettingPublisher(connectionString);
});